# How to change the color of every even row?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-selectors, font-awesome

I can't seem to make the right CSS selector to change the color of every other Font Awesome icon. After trying many different combinations (putting FA icon in a div, giving it different IDs and classes), this is the last thing I have:

HTML:

```
<div id="approachWrapper" class="col-xs-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <?php if (have_rows('approach_steps')):while(have_rows('approach_steps')):the_row();?>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 p-b-2 approachBox">
            <h2 class="text-xs-center p-t-2"><?php the_sub_field('approach_step');?></h2>
            <div class="approachIcon col-xs-12"><i id="iconColor" class="fa fa-<?php the_sub_field('approach_icon');?> fa-3x col-xs-12 text-xs-center"></i></div>
            <p class="text-xs-left"><?php the_sub_field('approach_description');?></p>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; else : endif; ?>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.approachIcon{
    color: white;
}
.approachIcon:nth-of-type(2n){
    color: #E0991B;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood your for loop properly you'll want something like this:

```css
div.approachBox:nth-child(even) { background-color: #FFFFFF; }
div.approachBox:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #E0991B; }
```

```html
<div id="approachWrapper" class="col-xs-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 p-b-2 approachBox">
        <h2 class="text-xs-center p-t-2">approach_step</h2>
        <div class="approachIcon col-xs-12"><i id="iconColor" class="fa fa-approach_icon fa-3x col-xs-12 text-xs-center"></i></div>
        <p class="text-xs-left">approach_description</p>
   </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 p-b-2 approachBox">
        <h2 class="text-xs-center p-t-2">approach_step</h2>
        <div class="approachIcon col-xs-12"><i id="iconColor" class="fa fa-approach_icon fa-3x col-xs-12 text-xs-center"></i></div>
        <p class="text-xs-left">approach_description</p>
   </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 p-b-2 approachBox">
        <h2 class="text-xs-center p-t-2">approach_step</h2>
        <div class="approachIcon col-xs-12"><i id="iconColor" class="fa fa-approach_icon fa-3x col-xs-12 text-xs-center"></i></div>
        <p class="text-xs-left">approach_description</p>
   </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 p-b-2 approachBox">
        <h2 class="text-xs-center p-t-2">approach_step</h2>
        <div class="approachIcon col-xs-12"><i id="iconColor" class="fa fa-approach_icon fa-3x col-xs-12 text-xs-center"></i></div>
        <p class="text-xs-left">approach_description</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/e74sr6ud/2/

> In fact, CSS allows not only allow even/odd alternations, but arbitrary intervals. The keywords 'even' and 'odd' are just convenient shorthands. For example, for a long list you could do this:

```
li:nth-child(5n+3) { font-weight: bold }
```

Source: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's looping through the whole `approachBox`:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 p-b-2 approachBox">
  <div class="approachIcon col-xs-12">...</div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 p-b-2 approachBox">
  <div class="approachIcon col-xs-12">...</div>
</div>

...
```

So you should set the selector like this:

```
.approachBox:nth-child(even) .approachIcon {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

in bootstrap, as it shown you are using given your classes you need `.container` and `.row` classes to wrap `.col-*-*` [more info bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

To color each icon you have to select the siblings which are the `.col-*-*` make them `odd` and `even` and finally target the `fa` class which belongs to `font-awesome` icon itself

```css
#approachWrapper > div:nth-of-type(2n) .fa {
  color: red
}
#approachWrapper > div:nth-of-type(2n+1) .fa {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="approachWrapper" class="col-xs-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 p-b-2 approachBox">
        <h2 class="text-xs-center p-t-2">test</h2>
        <div class="approachIcon col-xs-12"><i class="fa fa-user fa-3x col-xs-12 text-xs-center"></i>
        </div>
        <p class="text-xs-left">test</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 p-b-2 approachBox">
        <h2 class="text-xs-center p-t-2">test</h2>
        <div class="approachIcon col-xs-12"><i class="fa fa-user fa-3x col-xs-12 text-xs-center"></i>
        </div>
        <p class="text-xs-left">test</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 p-b-2 approachBox">
        <h2 class="text-xs-center p-t-2">test</h2>
        <div class="approachIcon col-xs-12"><i class="fa fa-user fa-3x col-xs-12 text-xs-center"></i>
        </div>
        <p class="text-xs-left">test</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```